# Python remove duplicates from array

Tags: python, csv

i've got an array wich contains an entire column from my csv file wich has alot of duplicates since the csv consist of users their contact info and their current group.

So the users in the CSV are in a group but sometime mulitple users are in the same group now the point of this python script is too sort all the users that are in the same group in a row like. i'll update the main thread so it wont confuse more ppl sorry.

The end goal is of this script will be to put the group in a row together with the phone numbers of the users that are in that group like this.

```
GroupName, PhoneNumber1, PhoneNumber2, PhoneNumber3, PhoneNumber4, etc
```

Example:

```
Name,  email, phonenumber, **group**
name1, name2, number1,     ExampleGroup
```

So i've tried sorting it by using this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

And it returns:

```
['a', ' ', 'E', 'g', 'i', 's', 'm', 'M', 'L', 'o', 'l', 'p', 'S', 'R', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n']
```

The code i'm using at the moment:

```
import csv
    with open('Configtool.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in reader:
         groupname = row[5]
         #print groupname
         sortedgroup = list(set(groupname))
         print sortedgroup
```

Your help is much appreciated,

**Note that i'm new to python so please go easy on me :p**

Comment: Dunno how you got the idea that `list(set(groupname))` was a way to sort things. Nothing like it appears on the page you linked.

Comment: What is duplicated in the file.. Is the entire column duplicated or an element of column has duplicated .. ?

Comment: I got it from another stackoverflow thread i found with similar problems.
@Rajsubit So the users in the CSV are in a group but sometime mulitple users are in the same group now the point of this python script is too sort all the users that are in the same group in a row  like. i'll update the main thread so it wont confuse more ppl sorry.

Comment: [use set()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: In your example you use `,`, but in the code you use `;` as delimiter. Also, the group is in column 4, i.e., index `[3]`, not `[5]`. BTW, what your code does is it takes the group name, turns it into a set, and back into a list. In other words, it scrambles the letters.

Comment: so you want the phone number of the users that are in a same group as one list? @B-W

Comment: @tobias_k i know in my source file there a couple more unsused colommns that are not used i only posted the relevant columns in the example the , is an thinking error on my behalve.

Comment: @Rajsubit Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.tee#itertools.groupby) to get all the rows with the same group and then use a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary mapping the groups to phone numbers.

```
import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(reader, key=lambda row: row[3])
d = {group: [row[2] for row in rows] for (group, rows) in groups}
```

(Assuming that the group in in position `3` and the phone number in position `2` of the rows. Also you might have to remove your loop, otherwise the `reader` iterator will already be exhausted.)

Comment: This works too a certain extend it will return a group and 1 phone number of the group and then it will return the same group but with another phone number.
The groups cant be duplicated and will need to return all the numbers of all the users that have the same group in one row.

Comment: If the groups really are the same, then it will work. Are there maybe whitespaces in the csv?, i.e. do you have groups like `'   group1'` and `' group1'`? Use this: `lines_clean = [map(str.strip, row) for row in reader]`